# Можно ли на ProgressBar'е что нибудь написать?

Tags: android, java, progress-bar

Есть такая задачка: ProgressBar показывает линию загрузки(статичная) и сверху него же написать его значение?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/124708/ - здесь описано подобное, но на основе TextView

Comment: @woesss спасибо! Это намного проще, чем вызывать onDraw().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наследуй **ProgressBar**, переопределяй метод **onDraw()** и пиши/рисуй все что душе угодно.

[пример](http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/23/android-progressbar-with-text/)

Comment: Ок! Спасибо! Плохо гуглил видимо)

Answer (score 0):

Варианта, на самом деле, два.

Первый вариант озвучен ответом выше, перезаписать метод onDraw() или PaintComponent()

Второй вариант - использовать возможности специализированных классов. Конкретнее в данном случае - BasicProgressBarUI. У любого компонента есть метод .setUI().

Вариант без создания дочернего класса:

`JProgressBar jp = new JProgressBar();
        jp.setUI(new ProgressBarUI() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
                super.paint(g, c);
            }
        });`

Выбор варианта немного спорен. По моим соображениям, второй вариант целесообразен для больших количеств компонентов, либо если в компоненте есть несколько состояний (кнопки, к примеру).